# viewDidLoad nor init are being called at application start iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

This is a novice error for sure. In Xcode 4 i have created a Window Based application in which i put a TabBarController as the root controller. When the application starts, the first tab of the tabbar is selected and thus the view corresponding to that tab is shown. The problem is that the View Controller that corresponds to that view in the first tab is not being read, i put some logs in the init, viewWillLoad, and viewDidLoad methods and none of them are being shown. I have linked the controllers correctly, plus Xcode links them automatic if you select that option when creating a new view controller. Here's how it looks like in my project.

**This is how it looks like in the tab controller i have linked to the view.nib:**
[image]

**And this is the view, it is linked to the view controller:** 
[image]

**And here's the View Connected to the File's Owner Outlet:** 
[image]

Everything looks fine for me so i don't understand why it's not calling those methods in the view controller when the application starts or when the tab corresponding to that view is being selected.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Have you connected HomeViewController's image referencing outlet to the view? Looks like you haven't.

Comment: I have done that already see the edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. The problem was that the referencing class was UIViewController intead of the view controller i created for it. The answer was to go to MainWindow.xib then select View Controller - Home then go to Identity Inspector and select the View Controller i created for it in this case the HomeViewController.h